# FAB not animated when one-line Snackbar is swiped away

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with support `FloatingActionButton` in which I want to display a `Snackbar`..

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_field"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_default"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_floating_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profile_floating_margin_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/brand_green"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/fac_icon_elevation"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I'm showing the Snackbar like this

```
Snackbar.make(mRootView, "Something went wrong", Snackbar.LENGHT_SHORT)
        .show();
```

When it's displayed, FAB slides up, when it (after LENGHT_SHORT) disappears, FAB slides down, all working fine.

However, if **I swipe the Snackbar away, FAB moves down without the slide animation**. It just flashes to its initial position.

**Interestingly, if the Snackbar has two lines** (no matter if it has an action or not) and is swiped away, **FAB animates back to its place correctly with the usual slide animation**.

Is that a bug in `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
or `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`? Any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin solution without using of a `ValueAnimator` based on [Matteo Destro's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028754/2311651):

```
class SnackBarAwareBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    companion object {
        private const val DURATION = 180
    }

    constructor() : super() {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    override fun layoutDependsOn(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: View,
        dependency: View
    ): Boolean {
        return dependency is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    }

    override fun onDependentViewChanged(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: View,
        dependency: View
    ): Boolean {
        if (dependency.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            moveChildUp(child, dependency.height + dependency.marginBottom)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onDependentViewRemoved(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: View, dependency: View) {
        moveChildToInitialPosition(child)
    }

    private fun moveChildUp(child: View, translation: Int) {
        child.animate()
            .translationY((-translation).toFloat())
            .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(DURATION.toLong())
            .start()
    }

    private fun moveChildToInitialPosition(child: View) {
        child.animate()
            .translationY(0f)
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(DURATION.toLong())
            .start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem recently and I've ended up creating a custom layout behavior class for the FAB to execute an animation when the snackbar is swiped away.

Create this class:

```java
public class SnackbarAwareBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 180;

    public SnackbarAwareBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public SnackbarAwareBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        if (dependency.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // Change the translation of the FAB only if the snackbar is visible
            child.setTranslationY(dependency.getTranslationY() - getTranslationYBottom(dependency));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull View child, @NonNull View dependency) {
        if (dependency.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.setTranslationY(0f);
        } else {
            // Execute the animation only if the snackbar has been swiped away, i.e. when it's not visible
            ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
            animator.setFloatValues(child.getTranslationY(), 0f);
            animator.setInterpolator(FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
            animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
            animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> child.setTranslationY((float) animation.getAnimatedValue()));
            animator.start();
        }
    }

    private int getTranslationYBottom(View view) {
        // Get the translation position of the snackbar when it's hidden.
        // Method taken from BaseTransientBottomBar.Behavior class.
        int translationY = view.getHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            translationY += ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layoutParams).bottomMargin;
        }
        return translationY;
    }

}
```

Then in your layout:

```xml
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      ...
      app:layout_behavior="your.package.SnackbarAwareBehavior">
```